# How to add a block in Luma header

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, theme-luma

How can I add a static block to the top header in Luma theme (see screenprint) ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header.promotion.message">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_promotion_message</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="header.promotion.message" destination="header.panel" before="-"/>
```

**Note: header_promotion_message is your Block Id**

[image]

Hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Add below code at after `top.search` referenceContainer:

> app/code/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">topPromo</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**Note:** Need to change block id `topPromo` with your block Id and need some CSS for positioning.